# replaced Button wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have this html form

```
   <form action="" method="post" name="login_form">
     Email :  <input type="text" id="email2" name="email" /><br />
     <span id="passwordT" >Password : </span> 
     <input type="password" name="password" id="password2"/><br />
     <input type="button" id="submit_botton" value="Login" />
     <div><input id="forgot" type="button" value="Forgot your Password?" /></div>
  </form>
```

and the javascript here

```
var forgot = $('#forgot');
var forgot2 = $('#forgot2');
forgot.click(function() {
   $('#password2').hide();
   $('span#passwordT').hide();
   $('input#submit_botton').prop('value', 'Reset Passowrd'); 
   $('input#forgot').replaceWith('<input id="forgot2" type="button" value="Login here" />');
});
$('input#forgot2').click(function() {        // this function didnt want to work
      $('input#forgot2').prop('value', 'Forgot your Password?');  
      $('#password2').show();
      $('span#passwordT').show();
      $('input#submit_botton').prop('value', 'Login'); 
 });
```

[HERE JS-DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3PETK/3/)

what i want is :
when i click on second function i will get back the buttons as they were in first time.

I tried to make this second function inside the first but what i got is the function works but only one time , i mean if i click again to reset password will not work.

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to attach an event handler to an element that doesn't exist yet. That's not possible with direct event handlers. Use delegated events instead.

```
$(document).on('click','#forgot2', function(){ ... });
```

`document` can be replaced with any `#forgot2` container that exists at binding time.

As a side note, take into account that when you use selectors by id (e.g `#forgot2`) it's not necessary to add anything else since an id identify one and just one element (repeated ids are not allowed). So this selector `input#forgot2` is not wrong but more complex than necessary.

Comment: The reason to do this is simple.  .click() applies the click event to a static set of elements.  No new elements will ever be added to this set.  Using delegation with .on() will apply to new matching elements as they are created.

Comment: your code works just one time, i mean if i click again on forget password will not work

Comment: yes worked well :) thanks i had to change also this to first function to - $(document).on('click','#forgot', function(){